# Scripting Edge to open preset list of URLs into separate tab groups in separate windows

Tags: microsoft-edge, servicenow

I'm a ServiceNow developer and throughout the day, I routinely need to log into three environments: Prod, Test, Dev.  I prefer having each environment in a separate window to encapsulate things.  I also prefer using Edge vs. Chrome because I use Chrome for my personal stuff and don't want to mix them up.  Or in the case of a browser crash, nuke the personal stuff I have open.

I know how to open each URL in a separate window and assign it to a new tab group.  That works great; the different colors easily identify which environment I'm in at a glance.  However, I'm getting sick of setting that up every day and really don't want to leave Edge running all the time.

Is there a way to create a macro or script that does the following:

1 - Opens URL#1 in a new Edge window, assigns it to a tab group "Production" and assigns the tab group the color green.
2 - Same process but Test and yellow.
3 - Same process but Development and red.

Unfortunately, I don't know PowerShell or any other scripting language other than Javascript, so hopefully someone can kick me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: ctrl + shift + t (in Chrome at least, most likely also Edge) will open up a previously closed tab. If you close your entire edge window (which then closes all tabs), then the next time you open Edge and do ctrl + shift + t it’ll open up all tab groups and tabs you previously had opened

Comment: I found that if you turn on [Pin tab group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66bIA.png), Edge will store the tab groups. So I think you just need to turn on that setting then open Edge with the same profile every time, the tab groups will show. No need to group tabs every time.

Comment: @Yu Zhou: Odd, I don't have that option.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4m935vklr2xchq/Capture.JPG?dl=0) 

Researching why that might be...

Comment: I should say that I'm on Windows 10 at the moment.  My CPU isn't compatible with Win11 yet.  :(  Currently on version 109.0.1518.70 (Official build) (64-bit).

Comment: Pin tab group is an old feature released many months ago. Which version of OS do you use? I only have Windows 10 VM which OS is 21H2 19044.2486. On this version, Edge 109 has this feature.

Comment: I'm on Win10 Enterprise v22H2 19045.2546.  Strange that I don't have that feature.  :P

Comment: Are Collections a similar construct maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can also use Collections.